# Network Printer shows as “Offline” in Windows 8.1

Tags: network-shares, windows-8.1, network-printer

Driver is installed, printer is OK and printing. Then after some reboots, the printer is shown as offline, or does not print, in Windows 8.1

Only returns if

```
reinstall it
```

or

```
NET STOP SPOOLER
NET START SPOOLER
```

Does anybody have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue; have had some success with setting the print spooler service to 'Delayed Start' but haven't tested this extensively yet.

I'm also going to investigate if newer drivers help with the issue.

Comment: On some cases, the user choose to use Windows 7, because of this instability in printing. On next time, I will try the 'Delayed Start'  option.